# Can I stop on custom loop iteration in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Hi my problem is that I have big array to loop through in my for cycle and on ~400th iteration some method fails. Can I make Idea debugger stop when i reaches for example i=400? If yes, than how can I do it? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by configuring a [breakpoint condition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-breakpoints.html) that will hit when `i==400`.