# Enable breakpoint after a number of hits

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to debug a huge collection of 760000 records but in record 54000 it hangs and I want to debug the loop but don't want to continue 54000 times manually.

Is it possible to put a condition in IntelliJ to stop the thread after a number of iterations?

**I Don't know the exact size of the collection as it is an Iterable and I don't know how to get the index.**

Edit: I guess I could work around it and edit the code to insert the counter in the loop and create a condition on a breakpoint to stop on the iteration I suspect wrong.

```
for (Item item: iterable) {
counter++;
}
```

And then condition the breakpoint.

counter==54000

**But unfortunately, I can't amend the code to add that counter.**

*Using Community Edition of IntelliJ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I stop on custom loop iteration in IntelliJ Idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341205/can-i-stop-on-custom-loop-iteration-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: start the loop at 54000?

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the breakpoint in question. It will open a small dialog box with a few options. Select `More` at the bottom. Now you will see a context menu where you can set "pass count".

You can enter it in that box, regardless of whether you want to set other special conditions on your breakpoint.

Comment: I don't have anything like this @Marc just 3 tick boxes Enabled Suspend and condition and the more options where i can't find any pass count option you mentioned.

Comment: Use the condition one. As I said you set it to stop when it hits the condition you set.

Comment: @johncliffe I understand but maybe I am being stupid here... How I can write a condition when i can't get the index of the enhanced for loop ?

Comment: @InjuredThePatient you have a counter in your code.

Comment: I have it under "more options". Do you use Community or Ultimate Edition? I have Ultimate.

Comment: @johncliffe please read the question again I said I could add it but I can't amend the code. Therefore This is and enhanced for loop with Iterable and this is my problem I can't get the index and the size of it without looping it thru. Or I am missing something here and don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @InjuredThePatient okay, so inside the code you see that counter? That will go up every time it goes through. So by the time you hit item 40,0000 counter will equal to 40000 so just stop debug when it hits the # you want.

Comment: @johncliffe he cant edit the code and he does not have a counter.

Comment: @InjuredThePatient then I think the Community Edition does not have this feature :(

Comment: @johncliffe its just to exclude potential suggestions to do it or to help people that can amend the code. its an example

Comment: @johncliffe as I understand it that is just an example how he could do it if he was able to change the code

Comment: @Marc I think is time to buy an ultimate edition then.

Answer (score 0):

Place a break point as usual, then right-click on it -> Properties. In the opened dialog there is a "Condition" edit box, here you could put your expression.

Comment: right then my shot probably is to create a counter in the enhanced for loop with Iterable and put the record in the condition i guess.

Comment: @InjuredThePatient fixed it

Comment: @Berger changed it.

Comment: You are not able to get the index and the size when using an enhanced for loop going though iterator i guess ?

Comment: @InjuredThePatient you should be able to set it so that it will stop when it huits a certain condition (ie the value you want)

Comment: Please ave a look  at my answer with the "pass count". Can use this eve if you can't edit the code.